# What is the Path to the Grave ability and how do I use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric

My cleric has an ability called *Path to the Grave*. I am confused about what it is and how I use it.

Specifically, I want to understand when and how I can cast this. Does it take spell slots? Is it independent of spell slots? Does it take reagents? How does it work? The description is unclear to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Path to the Grave is not a spell.  It is an option for the [cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric)'s Channel Divinity feature, available to clerics of the Grave domain at 2nd level.

Channel Divinity does not require spell slots. It is a class feature that the cleric can activate, although they have a limited number of usages between rests. Certain options may require a holy symbol or other divine focus, as specified in their description.

When a cleric of the Grave domain expends one of their Channel Divinity uses, they can choose whether to use Turn Undead or Path to the Grave.

> Channel Divinity
>
> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects. You start with two such effects: Turn Undead and an effect determined by your domain. Some domains grant you additional effects as you advance in levels, as noted in the domain description.
>
> When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose which effect to create. You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel Divinity again.

As for the effects of Path of the Grave, it requires an action, and targets a creature.

> As an action, you choose one creature you can see within 30 feet of you, cursing it until the end of your next turn. The next time you or an ally of yours hits the cursed creature with an attack, the creature has vulnerability to all of that attack’s damage, and then the curse ends.

[Vulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) means the cursed creature takes twice as much damage from a damage source. In this case, it would double the damage from one attack (likely either a weapon attack or spell attack).

> If a creature or an object has vulnerability to a damage type, damage of that type is doubled against it.

The vulnerability applies once. The "curse" ends if you or an ally successfully attack the creature, or at the end of your next turn, whichever happens first.

Answer (score 8):

### Path to the Grave only requires a use of your Channel Divinity feature

The Death Cleric's Path to the Grave feature states:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can **use your Channel Divinity** to mark another creature's life force for termination.

Channel Divinity is a feature every Cleric gets, and it states:

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects. **You start with two such effects: Turn Undead and an effect determined by your domain**...
>
> When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose which effect to create. **You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel Divinity again...**
>
> Beginning at 6th level, you can use your Channel Divinity twice between rests, and beginning at 18th level, you can use it three times between rests. When you finish a short or long rest, you regain your expended uses.

At level 2, this feature can be used once per short or long rest; both Turn Undead and Path to the Grave count as a use of Channel Divinity. Thus you can use either Path to the Grave or Turn Undead and then you must complete a short or long rest before you can use either again.
At later levels you get more uses of Channel Divinity between rests.
Notably Channel Divinity does not have any other requirements such as components, reagents, spell slots, or the like. You are only limited by your remaining uses.

The Path to the Grave features goes on to state:

> [...] As an action, you choose one creature you can see within 30 feet of you, cursing it until the end of your next turn. The next time you or an ally of yours hits the cursed creature with an attack, the creature has vulnerability to all of that attack's damage, and then the curse ends.

So what happens is you use your action, expending of use of Channel Divinity to activate Path to the Grave. You select a creature within 30 feet, and the effects of the curse apply; the first attack made by yourself an ally that hits the cursed creature will deal doubled damage, though only if the hit occurs before the end of your next turn.

Path to the Grave does not add on any new requirements in its description (Some Channel Divinities do, such as Turn Undead which says you "present your holy symbol"; the ramifications and requirements of that phrase are up your GM). With no additional requirements, Path to the Grave, just has the usual requirements of Channel Divinity, which is none; It only costs one use of your Channel Divinity feature.

Comment: Cool, and I believe your answer has benefited from that extra paragraph explaining that. +1